# Spring boot Data select shows old data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I update Database in webservice , when I execute select in db , row was update but when i call in my code row was not update.
also if call method once again , i see data updated

```
@Autowired
private CardMasterService cardMasterService;
@Autowired
private SoapWebserviceUtil webserviceUtil;
public CardConfidentialDataResponseDto getConfidentialData(CardConfidentialDataRequestDto requestDTO) {
    CardConfidentialDataResponseDto responseDto;
    try {
        CardMaster card = cardMasterService.findByCardNumber(requestDTO.getCardNumber());   
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMM");
        String expDate = df.format(card.getExpiryDate());
    String cvv2 = callGetClearMethod("GET_CLEAR_CVV2", card.getCardNumber(), expDate);  //Call web Service and update DB
        card = cardMasterService.findByCardNumber(requestDTO.getCardNumber());  // select DB show old data before update 
            Date jalaliiExpDate = PersianDateUtil.convertToJalali(card.getExpiryDate());
        String jalaiExpDateStr = df.format(jalaliiExpDate);
        responseDto = new CardConfidentialDataResponseDto(SUCCESSFUL.toString(), SUCCESSFUL.getDescription(), track1, track2, cvv2, card.getEmbossingName(), jalaiExpDateStr);
        return responseDto;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            responseDto = new CardConfidentialDataResponseDto(INTERNAL_ERROR.toString(), INTERNAL_ERROR.getDescription());
        }
        return responseDto;
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you're initializing `responseDto` except in the case of an error. So what should be returned? And what data did you update? Are you using any transaction markup? Are you reading and writing in the same transaction or different ones?

Comment: Update is correct because when i select excute in oracle db everythin is true,

Comment: Well, it may be correct but if you don't show the relevant portion it's hard to tell what your code is doing and where you might be wrong. Right now the code you've posted wouldn't compile because `responseDto` is not initialized in all cases.

Comment: Thanks,I change code to correct initialize responseDto, My main problem is like the link below   :                                                                                     
           https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6637

Comment: So `callGetClearMethod("GET_CLEAR_CVV2", card.getCardNumber(), expDate);` does the update? Does that run synchronously and in the same transaction as `cardMasterService.findByCardNumber(...)`? Did you put any transaction demarcation like `@Transactional` anywhere in the call hierarchy (might be on the classes only)?

Comment: Also note that the link you've posted describes a somewhat different situation so it might have a different cause. In any case we only can help find the cause if we have more info on your code, albeit putting all your code here might be too much so you'd need to be selective and maybe strip it down to relevant parts. Other than that we only can ask questions and try to point you into some direction that _might_ be the cause.

Comment: yes callGetClearMethod("GET_CLEAR_CVV2", card.getCardNumber(), expDate)  update db and i used                                                                                             @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: So you're updating and reading the database in 2 separate transactions? This could be the issue, i.e. you already read `card` prior to the update and thus it is in the 1st level cache that is attached to the read transaction. Since the update happens in a separate transaction that cache won't be updated and hence you get the cached entity. Try to evict card from the 1st level cache (not sure how exactly this is done in Spring Data), use a separate transactions for each read (or use one for everything) or mark the read transactions to not use the cache (again not sure how Spring would do that)

Comment: Thank yo so much